# Ng select dropdown is hidden by the dialog

Tags: css, angular

[The code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-jqdq7v?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I've tried using position fixed and z index, but the select remains fixed and when scrolled, it overlaps other content in the dialog

[image: this is the actual output i'm expecting]

Answer (score 13):

Default implementation of ng-select append these options with element, which when opening in dialog box depends on dialog box size. To display this outside of this dialog box or any parent element, need to append this with browser body.

```
<ng-select [searchable]="false" [appendTo]="'body'">
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how they work and why they work.

Comment: I need the search action to be preserved

Comment: search action as in? you are not clear. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to set input appendTo:
   `<ng-select **[appendTo]="'body'"**>...</ng-select>`
2. And add style in your component.ts:

```
::ng-deep .ng-dropdown-panel {
     z-index: 9999999!important;
 }
```

Comment: using `::ng-deep` its working!